# Transformar dado tipo long/varchar para string

Tags: mysql, python, python-2.7

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import MySQLdb as mdb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(plt)

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', '123456', 'testdb');
null = None
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    d = cur.execute("SELECT CAST(Ping AS DECIMAL(10,6)) as Ping FROM Pings WHERE Enderecos = 'www.peplink.com'")
    d = cur.fetchall()
    e = cur.execute("SELECT Timestamp FROM Pings WHERE Enderecos = 'www.peplink.com'")
    a = len(e)
    print a
    e = cur.fetchall()
    #plt.plot(d, e)
    #plt.title("Peplink")
    #plt.show()
```

Ele dá o seguinte erro:

```
    a = len(e)
    TypeError: object of type 'long' has no len()
```

Comment: E se fizer `a = len(str(e))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o seu problema fosse só esse, seria apenas fazer `len(str(e))`  - mas não resolveria nada - você só imprimiria a quantidade de dígitos do número "e" (isso é, se tivessem sido lidos 400 registros, isso resultaria em "3")
O número retornado pelo cursor.execute já é o número de linhas afetadas - 
em alguns drivers de banco de dados. EM outros, é preciso olhar a propriedade `.rowcount` do cursor.

Para de fato obter os resultados da consulta, após a chamada a `cur.execute(...)` chame `cur.fetchall()`  - isso retornara todos os resultados na forma de uma lista de Python.

Answer (score 0):

Se o objetivo é pegar o número de linhas retornadas na consulta, você pode utilizar a "rowcount", que é uma propriedade do cursor referente ao ultimo "execute":

```
e = cur.execute("SELECT Timestamp FROM Pings WHERE Enderecos = 'www.peplink.com'")
a = cur.rowcount   # a = len(e)
print a
```